# Using statistical query in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, phpmyadmin

I am trying to get count of proposals for each request that is posted in my site using statistical query.i.e, the count of proposals for each request that the logged in user has posted . I am getting the count of all users by using the code

```
return array(
   'serviceproposals' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Serviceproposal', 'ServiceRequestID'),
   'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Buyer', 'user_id'),
   'postCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'serviceproposal', 'ServiceRequestID'),
             );
```

Database:
    User[user_id,name,password],
    Provider[user_id,providercompany,providerdetails],
    Buyer[user_id,contactinfo],
    ServiceRequest[ServiceRequestID,Buyer.user_id,details,date],
    ServiceProposal[ServiceProposalId,ServiceRequestID,Provider.user_id,services,propsal_rate]

All suggestions are invited...

Comment: which model do those relations belong to?

Comment: @bool.dev ServiceRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to pass the `user_id` of the currently logged in user, to the `STAT` relation.

There are 2 ways of achieving this, use a [conditional query](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#dynamic-relational-query-options), or using [Parameterized named scopes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes)

1. Conditional Query.

   - Eager Loading:

     ```
     $obj= ServiceRequest::model()->with(array(
         'postCount'=>array('condition'=>'user_id = :param',
         'params' => array(':param' => $user_id))
     ))->findAll();
     ```
   - Lazy Loading:

     ```
     $serviceRequestObject->postCount(array(
         'condition'=>'user_id = :param',
         'params' => array(':param' => $user_id)
     ));
     ```
2. Parameterized Named Scope:
   In your model

   ```
   public function postCountUser($fieldValue=5) {
       $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
           'condition' => 'user_id = :param',
           'params' => array(':param' => $fieldValue)
      ));
      return $this;
   }
   ```

   Then use like:

   - Eager loading:

     ```
     ServiceRequest::model()->with('postCount')->postCountUser($user_id)->findAll();
     ```
   - Lazy Loading:

     ```
     $serviceRequestObj->postCount->postCountUser($user_id);
     ```

Comment: Is there any method to findout the maximum proposal_rate ?

Comment: ofcourse there is, use `'select'=>'MAX(proposal_rate)'`, i would recommend asking a new question, will give that new question more visibility, which will give you a chance of getting better, more detailed answers, as more users will try to attempt an answer. stackoverflow, doesn't work like forums, so please don't try to use it like one.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Bool..
You are helping me a lot.. :)

Comment: no problem, i'm glad that you are beginning to understand how s.o. works too.